# Database Restoration Issue Msg 3156, Level 16, State 6

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore

Recently while restoring a database with memory optimized filegroup I start facing an issue with below error message:-

> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2 File 'XYZ' cannot be restored to
>   'D:\FolderPath\Memory_Optimized_FolderName'. Use WITH MOVE to identify
>   a valid location for the file.

First I thought it might be syntax error but syntax was correct and I even checked the permission to filepath which was also fine. So what is the reason for this error?

Comment: What File does it refer to? N mdf/ndf/ldf or the memory optimized file (which in reality is a folder)?

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Memory Optimized file.

Comment: OK. I see you found the solution (I guessed that was it, but wanted to see what type of "file" is it, first....

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution of my problem which was folder location. The folder gets created itself. So once I removed the last folder name which was in some format

> "TableName_Memory_Optimized"

And using only below path in my restoration script it starts working fine.

> 'D:\FolderPath'